# When giving commands, when should I use the imperative and the infinitive?

Tags: grammaire, mode-grammatical, infinitif, impératif

I'm attempting to localise a game into French. Using other games as a guide for my less than perfect French grammar, I notice that sometimes a phrase that would use the imperative in English uses the infinitive in French. Some phrases however, use the imperative.

## Infinitive

> Select all → Tout sélectionner
>   Play → Jouer
>   Connect → Connecter
>   Send bonus moves → Envoyer des déplacements bonus

## Imperative

> Touch a sweet… → Touchez un bonbon…

Is there a rule for which to use? I observed that it might be that single word "commands" use the infinitive and longer phrases and sentences use the imperative. However the last infinitive example contradicts that observation.